# How to redirect on same page jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to redirect on same page, it is redirect after database storage. But giving me following error

> This page isn’t working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

My script is successfully saving record on database using php with jquery but after inserting data, it's giving me the above page error.

I have to refresh or press f5 in order to come on same page.

here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input").prop('required', true);
  /*---------------------------------------------------------*/
  $(".next_btn").click(function() { // Function Runs On NEXT Button Click
    $(this).parent().next().fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).parent().css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    // Adding Class Active To Show Steps Forward;
    $('.active').next().addClass('active');
  });
  $(".pre_btn").click(function() { // Function Runs On PREVIOUS Button Click
    $(this).parent().prev().fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).parent().css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    // Removing Class Active To Show Steps Backward;
    $('.active:last').removeClass('active');
  });


});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif);

/* Above line is to import google font style */

.content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  width: 650px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#progressbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}

fieldset {
  display: none;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 25px 1px gray;
}

#first {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 25px 1px gray;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password],
select {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(236, 176, 220);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(236, 176, 220);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=submit],
input[type=button] {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 15px 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: sienna;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}

h2,
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}

li {
  margin-right: 52px;
  display: inline;
  color: #c1c5cc;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}

p.eml {
  color: red;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

 $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sm123#",'crud');


if(isset($_POST["btnsave"]))
{
   $email=$_POST["email"];
   $password=$_POST["pass"];
   $qry="insert tbusr values(null,'$email','$password')";
  $res=mysqli_query($link,$qry);
  if(mysqli_affected_row($link)==1)
  {
    echo "Data inserted";
    
  }
  else
  {
      echo "Not";
  }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Myform</title>
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#email").change(function() {
          var a = $("#email").val();
          $('.eml').empty();
          $('.eml').append(a);
          console.log(a);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <!-- Multistep Form -->
      <div class="main">
        <form action="index.php" class="regform" method="post">
          <!-- Progress Bar -->
          <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Create Account</li>
            <li>Please View link</li>
            <li>Confirm Your Details</li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Fieldsets -->
          <fieldset id="first">
            <h2 class="title">Create your account</h2>
            <p class="subtitle">Step 1</p>
            <input class="text_field" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" id="email">
            <input class="text_field" name="pass" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            <input class="text_field" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
            <input class="next_btn" name="next" type="button" value="Next">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="title">Please View link</h2>
            <p class="subtitle">Step 2</p>
            <p>Please click On <b>View</b> to open verfication link tab</p>
            <input class="pre_btn" type="button" value="Previous">
            <input class="next_btn" name="next" type="button" value="View">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="title">Confirm Your Details</h2>
            <p class="subtitle">Step 3</p>
            <p>Please click here to confirm your email address</p>
            <p class="eml"></p>

            <input class="pre_btn" type="button" value="Previous">
            <input class="submit_btn" name="btnsave" type="submit" value="Confirm Email">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You need to check the PHP error logs for the reason you're getting the 500.

Comment: 500 is a server error  - ie your server code raised the error, not the client/javascript/jquery.  Step through the server code (or logs as above) to find the error.

Comment: Without the definition of `tbusr`, impossible to guess - but at a guess, your tbusr table is `id, email, password` and you're trying to insert nulls into id (or into another non-nullable column).

Comment: let me try ,, btw my id is auto increament @freedomn-m

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am just practising some code. At this time,  not concerned about the security

Comment: That's my point - you can't insert a null into a column that doesn't accept nulls.  If it's an auto-id then don't specify it in the insert.

Comment: " At this time, not concerned about the security"....nonetheless, if you're practicing, you should practice getting into good habits by writing your queries and storing your data in a safe way. Then when you come to do it for real it will be second nature and you won't even need to think about it. It's all that hard to do or learn (partly because there are so many examples / tutorials etc available, and partly because it doesn't require any particularly complicated code). Do things right from the beginning and then you won't have to re-write, re-test, re-learn or review anything later.

Comment: @ajaykumar have you done with this? do you still needing help?

Comment: Here's another security-related point to address along with the others (again, it's a good habit to get into, and a good task to learn):

Comment: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: @FernandoUrban Nope bro. Btw thanks